# Replace a string using vim

Tags: vim

I want to replace the 50th occurrence of `Alex` with `Alex(the father)` using vim.

The problem is this: after I execute the replace command, I want to search again for the word `Alex` and I do not want the replaced one to be displayed anymore. 
So when I do `gg49/Alex` and press 'n' I want vim to skip `Alex(the father)` and jump to the 51st occurance of `Alex` (51st in the original document).

So what I want is that vim does not show me the sub-string `Alex`, only the exact match. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this search with a negative lookahead against a left parenthesis to avoid matching `Alex` when it is followed by anything that starts with `(`.

```
/\<Alex\>\((\)\@!
```